# MVC 4: Area, routing and the views in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I added an area to my application. It is called "Examples". There is a default route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Examples_default",
    "Examples/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works fine if I have a controller called "MyExampleController.cs" and a View which is by default placed under Views/MyExample/Index.cshtml.
I can reach the url `"http://localhost/Examples/MyExample/Index"`.

What I want is just create a subfolder under Views to add one more level of organisation. I.e. under Views create a folder "NewExamples" and move MyExample there. So I may have the following structure

```
Views/NewExamples/MyExample/Index.cshtml
Views/OldExamples/Example123/Index.cshtml
```

etc.

I want to reach a url `"http://localhost/Examples/NewExamples/MyExample/Index"`.

I'm struggling with a route. My approach was to add a route before the default one:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Examples_newexamples",
    "Examples/NewExamples/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But that does not work. I hit my controller, but then I get the server error

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

```
~/Areas/Examples/Views/MyExample/Index.aspx
~/Areas/Examples/Views/MyExample/Index.ascx
~/Areas/Examples/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Areas/Examples/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
...
~/Areas/Examples/Views/MyExample/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/Examples/Views/MyExample/Index.vbhtml
~/Areas/Examples/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/Examples/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
...
```

So it doesn't even try to look into the NewExamples subfolder.

Is there a correct route to include this subfolder?

Comment: Checkout [Attribute Routing in MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

Comment: Why not simply `return View("~/Areas/Examples/Views/NewExamples/MyExample/Index.cshtml");`?

Comment: Thanks, this works. Will accept if you post as an answer. :) Just was hoping to achieve the same purely with routes as a more "elegant" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was generally useful `Route` attribute for this purpose:

```
[Route("~/Examples/NewExamples/MyExample/{id}")]
public ActionResult MyExample(it id)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Is it new in MVC 5? I'm still on MVC 4